# animating an attribute without animating other a attributes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, onmouseover

look at this code . when I hover an img , all of the images will animate to top . i don,t want this. I want if i hover mouse on any of them , just that one animate to top.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Majid</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            background: #333;
        }
        #box {
            width: 390px;
            height: 128px;
            margin-top: 300px;
            background: #555;
            position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
        }
#box a {
            width: 128px;
            height: 128px;
            float: left;
            margin: 0 1px;
        }
.icon img{position:relative;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function icons(){
   $("a img") .animate({top: '-125px'});
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <a href="JavaScript:();" onmouseover="icons();" class="icon"><img src="images/fb.jpg"   alt="" /></a>
        <a href="JavaScript:();" onmouseover="icons();" class="icon"><img src="images/tt.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="JavaScript:();" onmouseover="icons();" class="icon "><img src="images/gp.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your links to:

```
<a href="#" class="icon"><img src="images/fb.jpg"   alt="" /></a>
```

And your jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a img").on('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '-125px'
        });
    });
});
```

Be sure to wrap this jQuery in a document ready handler OR place it at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Add the following CSS:

```
#box a {
    transition: top 0.4s ease;
}
#box a:hover {
    top: -125px;
}
```

Now remove all JavaScript/jQuery/`onmouseover` events.

Comment: Where is the jQuery part... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I think you know that CSS is too awesome for jQuery ^_^

Comment: css??? no , i want if with jquery. because some people are useing win 7 and IE yet !!! and CSS3 doesn't run in IE of win 7.

Comment: Windows 7 supports IE10, which itself supports CSS3 transitions.

Comment: I don't think so! try it yourself. win 7 supports IE 9 . not the versions after that.

Comment: @user3503363 Considering I'm using IE11 on Windows 7 *right now*, you may wish to revise your statement. It's Windows XP that doesn't support anything past IE9, and that's because Windows XP is no longer supported, period.

Comment: mmmm ... I tried it once and didn't get successful .